# Jekyll: Dealing with Images in Markdown

Tags: image, markdown, jekyll, image-gallery

I've got a design for my post page that is made up of text and images, more specifically, galleries. Take a look at the illustration below:

[image]

I've got these galleries set up my front matter like so:

```
---
gallery-1:
  rows:
    - images:
      -  { url: '1.jpg'}
    - images:
      -  { url: '2.jpg'}
      -  { url: '3.jpg'}
gallery-2:
  rows:
    - images:
      -  { url: '4.jpg'}
      -  { url: '5.jpg'}
---
```

Is there a way to print these galleries to the page on my `.md` file. I know the code below won't work, but something similar?

```
This is my markdown

[gallery-1]

This is more markdown

[gallery-2]
```

Is something like this possible with Jekyll?

Any help with this is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's simplify your `yaml front matter` :

```
---
galleries:
 # gallery number one
 1:
   # row one in gallery one
   -
     - { url: '1.jpg', alt: 'alt 1'}
   # row two in gallery one
   -
     - { url: '2.jpg', alt: 'alt 2'}
     - { url: '3.jpg', alt: 'alt 3'}

 # gallery number two
 2:
  # row one in gallery two
   -
     - { url: '4.jpg', alt: 'alt 4'}
     - { url: '5.jpg', alt: 'alt 5'}

other front matter like title, ...
---
```

Your `.md` file :

```
Markdown
{% include gallery.html  gallery=1 %}
Other markdown
{% include gallery.html  gallery=2 %}
```

And then the `_includes/gallery.html` file :

```
{% comment %}-----------------
  - This page receives a gallery index (include.gallery)
  - It then assign the gallery[include.gallery] to the rows variable
%}-----------------{% endcomment %}
{% assign rows = page.galleries[include.gallery] %}

{% comment %}%}-----------------
  We now loop over rows
%}-----------------{% endcomment %}
{% for row in rows %}
<div class="row">
    {% comment %}%}-----------------
      and then loop over images in row
    %}-----------------{% endcomment %}
    {% for img in row %}
        <p>src="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ img.url }}" alt="{{ img.alt }}"</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

See [yaml documentation](http://yaml.org/spec/1.0/#id2489726) And [Jekyll template documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#includes)

Comment: This is massively helpful! Totally forgot I could utilise the `{% include %} tag`. Thanks for the help. P.S. You're using an array for the rows, can I change that back to an object so I can use values such as url and title so I can give pass these to my `<img>` tag?

Comment: I've edited my answer to manage image objects in yaml front matter. Also edited _includes/gallery.html.

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I was looking for. I'm trying to close out a container tag at the top of that `gallery.html` and re-open it at the end of the include, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any reason why?

Comment: First look at the generated markdown, sometimes you can be in a <p> tag. Second look at you layout inheritance. If still in trouble push the code to github and ask a new question.

Comment: Any closing tag that starts of the top of that includes file, automatically gets converted to a `<p>` tag. Weird. Hmm... I'll try and work it out, and post a question if I'm still stuck.

Comment: @DavidJacquel where does the YAML front matter in the initial portion of your post go?  Is your answer still the same in 2022?

Comment: @jml galleries datas are placed in a post or page front matter.
And I guess it's still working in 2022 ;-)